# Convert DataTable to Dictionary<string,string> specifying the column-names involved, not using foreach

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, datatable, ado.net

No problem at all doing this with a loop, but I was wondering if there are built-in conversion functions which, when used together, could move the data in an ADO.NET `DataTable` (that contains more than two columns) into to a `Dictionary<string,string>` in a one-liner, where the column with the keys and the column with the values are specified by name not index position.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this, but by reading the docs:

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> dic =
     dataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
     .Select(row => dataTable.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
                    .ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col => row[col] != null ? row[col].ToString() : null));
```

You asked for a one-liner :)

Comment: Yes, I did ask for a one liner :)    Thanks.  I will test when I get in to the office later.